# JavaFX: How to trigger TreeItem event

Tags: events, javafx, treetable

I have class `myClass extends TreeItem<file>` to be used as datamodel in a `TreeTableView` mostly following the example here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html .

```
public class myTreeItem extends TreeItem<File> 
     private boolean isLeaf;
     private boolean isFirstTimeChildren = true;
     private boolean isFirstTimeLeaf = true;

     @Override public ObservableList<TreeItem<File>> getChildren() {
             // ... full code see link to Oracle documentation
      return super.getChildren();
      }

      private ObservableList<TreeItem<File>> buildChildren(TreeItem<File> TreeItem) {
             // ... full code see link to Oracle documentation
      };
}
```

I have added a function to add children to this item. I have problems with the correct update of the `TreeTableView`. More details see in the code and comments below:

```
public void addChild(String name) {
    itemManger.addChild(this.getValue(), name);  // Generate Child
    isFirstTimeChildren = true;       // Ensure that buildChildren() is called, when getchildren() is called. 

//  getChildren();                    // If I would activate this line, 
                                      // all listeners would be notified 
                                      // and the TreeTableView is updated. 
                                      // This is most likely due to the call super.getChildren();

   // However I want to throw the event on my own in order 
   // to avoid the extra call of  this.getChildren(). Here is my 
   // (not sufficent) try:
    EventType<TreeItem.TreeModificationEvent<MLDCostumizableItem>> eventType =  TreeItem.treeNotificationEvent();
    TreeModificationEvent<MLDCostumizableItem> event = new TreeModificationEvent<>(eventType,this);
    Event.fireEvent(this,  event);


    // Here I don't know how to get a value for target. 
    // Is there some standard target, which includes all FX components?

}
```

How the correctly throw this event?

Comment: Whether you immeditely refresh the list or trigger an event that causes the list to be refreshed should have the same effect and the performance of the former approach would be better, so why not call `getChildren()` to cause a refresh? If you do not want unnecessary refreshs, just check, if all ancestors are expanded...

Comment: I also want to get a deeper understanding on FX triggers. Therefore my question.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do here, but typically I think you would create a `TreeItem.TreeModificationEvent` using an appropriate constructor, and then provide a `TreeItem` as the target in `Event.fire(...)`.

Comment: Thanks James_D. I tried to do this. See my edit. However I don't know how to best define the `target` in `Event.fire(...)`. Now I used `this` which compiles w/o error. Anyhow the `TreeTableView` which uses this `TreeTableItem` is not updated. Seems that I have to modify the `target`. Is there a generic possibility to acess the `TreeTableView` out of the `TreeTableItem` or do I have to store this information using the constructor of `TreeTableItem`?

Comment: Digging deeper in the code of `javafx.scene.control.TreeItem` is now (think to) understand that `super.getChildren()` does not itself trigger an event (like I tried). Instead the `ObservabelList<> children` itself notifies the observers when it is changed. Kindly confirm or correct my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I had a missunderstanding in how the triggering works in JavaFX. Now the most simple solution is:

```
@Override  // Taken from Link
public void update(Observable observ, Object arg1)  {
    if (observ!=this.item)
    {
        LOGGER.error(new MLDConnectionException("Unexpected call of update() with observ = " + observ.toString()));
        return;
    }
    // Build new Chidren list
    try {
        super.getChildren().removeIf((x) -> true);  // empty list
        super.getChildren().setAll(buildChildren(this));
    } catch (MLDConnectionException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error when genereting children List: ", e);
    }

}

public File addChild(String name) throws MLDException {

    File newChild = itemManger.addChild(item, name);
    update(this.item, null);
    return newChild;
}
```